# Error updating existing ruby on rails App on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, heroku

This app, "ecozap" was developed by another developer five years ago, it is relased, I have to make design changes and css styles ...

Finally, when I push to heroku I´m getting the following error:

```
C:\Sites\ecozap_v1>heroku logs --app ecozap
2014-01-29T08:05:45.331582+00:00 app[web.1]: While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you
change the version of just one of them later.
2014-01-29T08:05:45.331582+00:00 app[web.1]: You should probably keep only one of them.
2014-01-29T08:05:49.108557+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.1.11 application starting in production on http:
//0.0.0.0:27698
2014-01-29T08:05:49.108557+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2014-01-29T08:05:49.109799+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1
1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:112:in `block in build'
2014-01-29T08:05:49.109799+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.11/lib/ac
tion_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:43:in `build': undefined method `new' for ExceptionNotifier:Module (No
MethodError)
2014-01-29T08:05:49.109799+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1
1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:112:in `inject'
2014-01-29T08:05:49.109799+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:37:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2014-01-29T08:05:49.109799+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2014-01-29T08:05:49.108557+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2014-01-29T08:05:49.109957+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2014-01-29T08:05:49.108557+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2014-01-29T08:05:49.108557+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2014-01-29T08:05:49.109957+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2014-01-29T08:05:49.109799+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1
1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:112:in `build'
2014-01-29T08:05:49.109799+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2014-01-29T08:05:49.109957+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
2014-01-29T08:05:49.109957+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2014-01-29T08:05:49.109957+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:8:in `require'
2014-01-29T08:05:49.109799+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1
1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:112:in `each'
2014-01-29T08:05:49.109957+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/
rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2014-01-29T08:05:49.109799+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/engine.rb:447:in `app'
2014-01-29T08:05:49.109957+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2014-01-29T08:05:49.109957+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:8:in `block in <main>'
2014-01-29T08:05:49.109957+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/
rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2014-01-29T08:05:49.110117+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2014-01-29T08:05:49.109799+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2014-01-29T08:05:49.110117+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/
rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2014-01-29T08:05:49.110117+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/
rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2014-01-29T08:05:49.110117+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/
rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2014-01-29T08:05:49.110117+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2014-01-29T08:05:49.109957+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2014-01-29T08:05:49.110117+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2014-01-29T08:05:49.110546+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2014-01-29T08:05:49.110117+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/
rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
2014-01-29T08:05:49.110117+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/
rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
2014-01-29T08:05:49.110117+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `tap'
2014-01-29T08:05:49.110546+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `require'
2014-01-29T08:05:49.110546+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `<top (required)>'
2014-01-29T08:05:49.110117+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/commands.rb:54:in `block in <top (required)>'
2014-01-29T08:05:50.377278+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-01-29T08:05:50.389210+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-01-29T08:05:50.390041+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-01-29T08:05:54.517754+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed
to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2014-01-29T08:05:54.517978+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2014-01-29T08:05:56.651835+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server
-p 24949`
2014-01-29T08:05:56.999573+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2014-01-29T08:05:58.434930+00:00 app[web.1]: Your Gemfile lists the gem sqlite3-ruby (>= 0) more than on
ce.
2014-01-29T08:05:58.434930+00:00 app[web.1]: You should probably keep only one of them.
2014-01-29T08:05:58.434930+00:00 app[web.1]: While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you
change the version of just one of them later.
2014-01-29T08:05:58.435307+00:00 app[web.1]: Your Gemfile lists the gem rspec-rails (= 2.7.0) more than
once.
2014-01-29T08:05:58.435307+00:00 app[web.1]: You should probably keep only one of them.
2014-01-29T08:05:58.435307+00:00 app[web.1]: While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you
change the version of just one of them later.
2014-01-29T08:05:58.438249+00:00 app[web.1]: Your Gemfile lists the gem rspec-core (= 2.7.1) more than o
nce.
2014-01-29T08:05:58.438249+00:00 app[web.1]: While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you
change the version of just one of them later.
2014-01-29T08:05:58.438519+00:00 app[web.1]: Your Gemfile lists the gem rspec (>= 0) more than once.
2014-01-29T08:05:58.438249+00:00 app[web.1]: You should probably keep only one of them.
2014-01-29T08:05:58.438519+00:00 app[web.1]: While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you
change the version of just one of them later.
2014-01-29T08:05:58.438519+00:00 app[web.1]: You should probably keep only one of them.
2014-01-29T08:06:04.215394+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2014-01-29T08:06:04.215394+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.1.11 application starting in production on http:
//0.0.0.0:24949
2014-01-29T08:06:04.215394+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2014-01-29T08:06:04.215394+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2014-01-29T08:06:04.215394+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2014-01-29T08:06:04.216479+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.11/lib/ac
tion_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:43:in `build': undefined method `new' for ExceptionNotifier:Module (No
MethodError)
2014-01-29T08:06:04.216479+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1
1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:112:in `block in build'
2014-01-29T08:06:04.216479+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1
1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:112:in `each'
2014-01-29T08:06:04.216479+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1
1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:112:in `build'
2014-01-29T08:06:04.216479+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/engine.rb:447:in `app'
2014-01-29T08:06:04.216479+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:37:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2014-01-29T08:06:04.216479+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2014-01-29T08:06:04.216952+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2014-01-29T08:06:04.216479+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1
1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:112:in `inject'
2014-01-29T08:06:04.216952+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
2014-01-29T08:06:04.216952+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2014-01-29T08:06:04.216952+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:8:in `block in <main>'
2014-01-29T08:06:04.216952+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2014-01-29T08:06:04.216479+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2014-01-29T08:06:04.216952+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2014-01-29T08:06:04.216952+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2014-01-29T08:06:04.216952+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:8:in `require'
2014-01-29T08:06:04.217116+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2014-01-29T08:06:04.217116+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2014-01-29T08:06:04.217116+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/
rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2014-01-29T08:06:04.217116+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/
rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2014-01-29T08:06:04.217116+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2014-01-29T08:06:04.217463+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/
rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
2014-01-29T08:06:04.216952+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/
rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2014-01-29T08:06:04.217463+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `<top (required)>'
2014-01-29T08:06:04.217463+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2014-01-29T08:06:04.217463+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/commands.rb:54:in `block in <top (required)>'
2014-01-29T08:06:04.217463+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `tap'
2014-01-29T08:06:04.216952+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/
rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2014-01-29T08:06:04.217463+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2014-01-29T08:06:04.217116+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/
rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
2014-01-29T08:06:04.217116+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/
rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2014-01-29T08:06:04.217463+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `require'
2014-01-29T08:06:05.790709+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-01-29T08:06:05.809126+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-01-29T08:06:06.537495+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 87.218.164.248 - - [29/Jan/2014:08:06:06 +0000] "GET / H
TTP/1.1" 503 409 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.17
00.76 Safari/537.36" ecozap.es
2014-01-29T08:06:06.533400+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/
host=ecozap.es request_id=591e9355-2b57-423d-817c-6a633b0ebe62 fwd="87.218.164.248" dyno= connect= servi
ce= status=503 bytes=

C:\Sites\ecozap_v1>
```

This is my Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

#ruby '1.9.3'

gem 'rails', "= 3.1.11"
#gem "rake", "= 0.8.7"
gem 'racc'
# gem 'sqlite3'
#gem 'acts_as_list', '>= 0.1.0'
#gem 'acts_as_tree'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'gravatar_image_tag'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 2.1'
gem 'RedCloth', '>= 3.301'
gem 'carmen', :git => 'git://github.com/alvatarc/carmen.git', :branch => '0.2.x'
#gem 'carmen'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'http_accept_language'
gem 'right_aws'
gem 'exception_notification'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '= 2.7.0'
  gem 'rspec-core', '= 2.7.1'
  gem 'rspec'
  #gem 'annotate-models'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'therubyracer'
end

group :test do
  gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '= 2.7.0'
  gem 'rspec-core', '= 2.7.1'
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'webrat'
  gem 'spork', '= 0.9.0.rc9'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'uglifier'
end


# To use debugger (ruby-debug for Ruby 1.8.7+, ruby-debug19 for Ruby 1.9.2+)
# gem 'ruby-debug'
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
```

This is my Gemfile.lock:

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/alvatarc/carmen.git
  revision: af7bcd574e2f0ed6d59b46662a8be939a1e083c0
  branch: 0.2.x
  specs:
    carmen (0.2.13)

GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    RedCloth (4.2.9)
    RedCloth (4.2.9-x86-mingw32)
    actionmailer (3.1.11)
      actionpack (= 3.1.11)
      mail (~> 2.3.3)
    actionpack (3.1.11)
      activemodel (= 3.1.11)
      activesupport (= 3.1.11)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      rack (~> 1.3.6)
      rack-cache (~> 1.2)
      rack-mount (~> 0.8.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.0.4)
    activemodel (3.1.11)
      activesupport (= 3.1.11)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
    activerecord (3.1.11)
      activemodel (= 3.1.11)
      activesupport (= 3.1.11)
      arel (~> 2.2.3)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.1.11)
      activemodel (= 3.1.11)
      activesupport (= 3.1.11)
    activesupport (3.1.11)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    arel (2.2.3)
    aws-s3 (0.6.3)
      builder
      mime-types
      xml-simple
    aws-sdk (1.9.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.4)
      uuidtools (~> 2.1)
    builder (3.0.4)
    climate_control (0.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
    cocaine (0.5.1)
      climate_control (>= 0.0.3, < 1.0)
    diff-lcs (1.1.3)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    exception_notification (3.0.1)
      actionmailer (>= 3.0.4)
    execjs (1.4.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    factory_girl (4.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (4.2.1)
      factory_girl (~> 4.2.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    faker (1.1.2)
      i18n (~> 0.5)
    ffi (1.9.3-x86-mingw32)
    gravatar_image_tag (1.1.3)
    hike (1.2.2)
    http_accept_language (1.0.2)
    i18n (0.6.4)
    jquery-rails (2.2.1)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.7.7)
    kaminari (0.14.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    libv8 (3.11.8.17)
    mail (2.3.3)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.23)
    multi_json (1.7.2)
    nokogiri (1.5.9)
    nokogiri (1.5.9-x86-mingw32)
    paperclip (3.4.1)
      activemodel (>= 3.0.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      cocaine (~> 0.5.0)
      mime-types
    pg (0.15.1)
    pg (0.15.1-x86-mingw32)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    racc (1.4.9)
    rack (1.3.10)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-mount (0.8.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    rack-ssl (1.3.3)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.1.11)
      actionmailer (= 3.1.11)
      actionpack (= 3.1.11)
      activerecord (= 3.1.11)
      activeresource (= 3.1.11)
      activesupport (= 3.1.11)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.1.11)
    railties (3.1.11)
      actionpack (= 3.1.11)
      activesupport (= 3.1.11)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (~> 0.14.6)
    rake (10.0.4)
    rdoc (3.12.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    ref (1.0.4)
    right_aws (3.0.5)
      right_http_connection (>= 1.2.5)
    right_http_connection (1.3.0)
    rspec (2.7.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.7.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.7.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.7.0)
    rspec-core (2.7.1)
    rspec-expectations (2.7.0)
      diff-lcs (~> 1.1.2)
    rspec-mocks (2.7.0)
    rspec-rails (2.7.0)
      actionpack (~> 3.0)
      activesupport (~> 3.0)
      railties (~> 3.0)
      rspec (~> 2.7.0)
    sass (3.2.8)
    sass-rails (3.1.7)
      actionpack (~> 3.1.0)
      railties (~> 3.1.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3.2)
    spork (0.9.0.rc9)
    spork (0.9.0.rc9-x86-mingw32)
      win32-process
    sprockets (2.0.4)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.7)
    sqlite3 (1.3.7-x86-mingw32)
    sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
      sqlite3 (>= 1.3.3)
    therubyracer (0.11.4)
      libv8 (~> 3.11.8.12)
      ref
    thor (0.14.6)
    tilt (1.3.7)
    treetop (1.4.12)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.37)
    uglifier (2.0.1)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    uuidtools (2.1.3)
    webrat (0.7.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.2.0)
      rack (>= 1.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.3)
    win32-process (0.7.4)
      ffi (>= 1.0.0)
    xml-simple (1.1.2)

PLATFORMS
  ruby
  x86-mingw32

DEPENDENCIES
  RedCloth (>= 3.301)
  aws-s3
  aws-sdk
  carmen!
  exception_notification
  factory_girl_rails
  faker
  gravatar_image_tag
  http_accept_language
  jquery-rails (~> 2.1)
  kaminari
  paperclip
  pg
  racc
  rails (= 3.1.11)
  right_aws
  rspec
  rspec-core (= 2.7.1)
  rspec-rails (= 2.7.0)
  sass-rails
  spork (= 0.9.0.rc9)
  sqlite3-ruby
  therubyracer
  uglifier
  webrat
```

Those are my installed gems:

```
C:\Sites\ecozap_v1>gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.13, 3.1.11)
actionpack (3.2.13, 3.1.11)
activemodel (3.2.13, 3.1.11)
activerecord (3.2.13, 3.1.11)
activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (3.2.10)
activeresource (3.2.13, 3.1.11)
activesupport (3.2.13, 3.1.11)
addressable (2.3.5)
arel (3.0.3, 3.0.2, 2.2.3)
aws-s3 (0.6.3)
aws-sdk (1.9.2)
bigdecimal (1.1.0)
builder (3.0.4)
bundler (1.3.4)
climate_control (0.0.3)
cocaine (0.5.1)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.6.3, 1.6.1)
diff-lcs (1.1.3)
erubis (2.7.0)
eventmachine (1.0.3 x86-mingw32)
exception_notification (3.0.1)
excon (0.25.3)
execjs (2.0.2, 1.4.0)
factory_girl (4.2.0)
factory_girl_rails (4.2.1)
faker (1.1.2)
ffi (1.9.3 x86-mingw32)
gravatar_image_tag (1.1.3)
heroku (3.1.0)
heroku-api (0.3.15)
hike (1.2.3, 1.2.2, 1.2.1)
http_accept_language (1.0.2)
i18n (0.6.4, 0.6.1)
io-console (0.3)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (3.0.4, 2.2.1)
json (1.8.1, 1.7.7, 1.5.5)
kaminari (0.14.1)
launchy (2.4.2)
libv8 (3.11.8.17)
mail (2.5.4, 2.5.3, 2.3.3)
mime-types (1.25.1, 1.23, 1.21)
minitest (2.5.1)
multi_json (1.8.4, 1.8.2, 1.7.2, 1.7.1)
mysql (2.9.1 x86-mingw32)
netrc (0.7.7)
node (0.0.2)
nokogiri (1.5.9 x86-mingw32)
paperclip (3.4.1)
pg (0.15.1 x86-mingw32, 0.14.1 x86-mingw32)
polyglot (0.3.3)
racc (1.4.9)
rack (1.4.5, 1.3.10)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-mount (0.8.3)
rack-ssl (1.3.3)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (3.2.13, 3.1.11)
railties (3.2.13, 3.1.11)
rake (10.1.1, 10.1.0, 10.0.4, 10.0.3, 0.9.2.2)
rb-readline (0.4.2)
rdoc (3.12.2, 3.9.5)
RedCloth (4.2.9 x86-mingw32)
ref (1.0.4)
rest-client (1.6.7)
right_aws (3.0.5)
right_http_connection (1.3.0)
rspec (2.7.0)
rspec-core (2.7.1)
rspec-expectations (2.7.0)
rspec-mocks (2.7.0)
rspec-rails (2.7.0)
ruby (0.1.0)
rubyzip (0.9.9)
sass (3.2.13, 3.2.12, 3.2.8, 3.2.7)
sass-rails (3.2.6, 3.1.7)
spork (0.9.0.rc9 x86-mingw32)
sprockets (2.2.2, 2.0.4)
sqlite3 (1.3.8 x86-mingw32, 1.3.7 x86-mingw32)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
therubyracer (0.11.0beta1 x86-mingw32)
thor (0.18.1, 0.17.0, 0.14.6)
tilt (1.4.1, 1.3.7, 1.3.6)
tiny_tds (0.5.1 x86-mingw32)
treetop (1.4.15, 1.4.12)
tzinfo (0.3.38, 0.3.37)
uglifier (2.4.0, 2.3.2, 2.0.1)
uuidtools (2.1.3)
webrat (0.7.3)
win32-process (0.7.4)
xml-simple (1.1.2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you discovered, you needed to do a migration. But also, make sure your *Gemfile* and *Gemfile.lock* have been pushed to Heroku. That usually helps gem problems like the one you seem to be having with the [exception_notification](https://github.com/rails/exception_notification) plugin.

Comment: how could I make sure that those files have been pushed?@Vidya

Comment: Just make sure those files are part of source control with a `add` and `commit`. Then when you push, they will be pushed too.

Comment: I've made sure of Gemfile and Gemfile.lock are pushed on Heroku, but I'm using Windows, Heroku remove Gemfile.lock during the pushing, because it's generated on Windows. I've edited main post with more data, I thank to you all the given help.

Comment: That's your problem. Be specific with al your gem versions in the Gemfile. Also, consider deleting the Windows stuff from Gemfile.lock. See [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile).

Comment: The programmer that create the app developed it on Linux, It's me the one who is using Windows to modify the styles. Have I uninstall all gems and reinstall them one by one manually?, without using `bundle install` command.

Answer (score 0):

To take from [dylanjhunt's awesome answer on Github](https://github.com/wpscanteam/wpscan/issues/876#issuecomment-170403692)

> Just to add to this, I was having a very similar issue that was
>   resolved by updating dev tools.
>
> `xcode-select --install`
>
> Hoping someone sees this that had not tried doing this yet and it
>   helps.